# Using StructKeyExists on a cfquery result

Tags: cfml, railo

I have a list of column names and loop over them to see if a name exists as a key in struct using 'StructKeyExists' - works as expected.

But when I try the same on a single row cfquery result it also works - I expected it to crash.

Why does it work on a cfquery results?

I'd expect to have issues if the cfquery result had more than 1 row, but in this case biz rules don't allow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is checking the structure key not the individual rows in the query. So if you query has a column named "id" or "columnName" and you use structkeyexists to check for the key, e.g. "id" or "columnName" you are asking CFML if that query has a column named that. How many rows the query has returned is in no way related.

Comment: ... I realized that much. I expected 'StructKeyExists' to apply exclusively to a stuct and not query result. It's almost as it the query and struct here the same datatype under the hood.

Comment: Yes, a query is essentially a structure of arrays see this article by Ray Camden https://www.raymondcamden.com/2009/11/25/Quick-Tip-Treating-a-ColdFusion-Query-like-a-Structure